# How to programmatically copy a folder from a plugin to a new project in the work space?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse Plugin creating a new Project Wizard. When creating such new project in the workspace I need it to copy a folder, and its descendent, from the plugin to the just created project in the workspace. The problem is that while the project is an `IResource` the plugin folder is in the file system.

I succeeded in getting an URL for the source plugin folder I need to copy and I have the IProject reference.

What I need to know is: How to copy the former into the latter?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8478944/150166) to see how to get a file/folder "out of" a plugin.

Then create new files/folders in the projects and set file contents using `InputStream`:

```java
void copyFiles (File srcFolder, IContainer destFolder) {
    for (File f: srcFolder.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            IFolder newFolder = destFolder.getFolder(new Path(f.getName()));
            newFolder.create(true, true, null);
            copyFiles(f, newFolder);
        } else {
            IFile newFile = destFolder.getFile(new Path(f.getName()));
            newFile.create(new FileInputStream(f), true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I did managet to get a folder out of a plugin but I actually need to copy a folder and subfolders not just a file. I guess by InputStream I only can copy files content not the whole folder (and related contents). Any advice?

Comment: @Silli A little recursion will help out.

Comment: Does the bundle necessary need to be unpacked that I can be able to read files from it?

Comment: @DannyLo Well, I'm sure it's possible to read from the bundle directly, but if you're using Eclipse resource API then it unpacks the requested entries automatically.

Comment: @MarttiKäärik I am asking because I'm [having problems with empty folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235880/filelocators-method-tofileurl-ignores-empty-folders).

Comment: What if a directory with the same name already exists in the target? Then this code just fails, right? Or is anything overwritten?

Comment: Also, it seems like it will fail if parent directories to `destFolder` does not exist. In that case it seems like you must use the technique described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8606975/452775).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without knowing exactly the files (you cannot iterate over the children). Instead of using a folder with files and subfolders, create a zip with that structure and unpack the zip in your workspace (this should preserve the desired structure).

Comment: this is a good advice thank you. How do I unpack programmatically?

Comment: A good starting point is the snippet at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1303771/173101 or use the documentation at http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Comment: @Silli Eclipse `FileLocator.toFileURL()` will unpack the files for you **if** necessary.

Comment: @TomSeidel You *can* iterate over the children of a specific path using org.osgi.framework.Bundle#getEntryPaths(String). With proper recursion you can copy entire trees from the plug-in into the workspace, reading the returned URL's input streams to create the files and folders.