# Copy files from filesystem to a project and correctly manage the progress monitor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, progressmonitor

I am trying to modify [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792260/eclipse-how-to-programmatically-copy-a-folder-from-a-plugin-to-a-new-project-in/8792373#8792373) answer for my needs and to make the progress monitor reflect the progress correctly. My approach till now:

```
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.SubProgressMonitor;

private void configureProject(IProgressMonitor monitor)
    throws CoreException, IOException
{
    try
    {
        URL templatesURL = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry(TEMPLATES);
        File templatesFolder = new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(templatesURL).getPath());
        int fileCount = getElementsCount(templatesFolder);

        monitor.beginTask("Creating file structure for new project...", fileCount + 5);

        project.getFolder(P_SRC).delete(true, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));
        project.getFolder(P_BIN).delete(true, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));

        copyFiles(templatesFolder, project, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, fileCount));
        project.getFile(P_TOUCH).delete(true, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));

        IClasspathEntry[] newEntries = new IClasspathEntry[3];
        newEntries[0] = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(getCreatedElement().getPath().append(SRC_MAIN));
        newEntries[1] = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(getCreatedElement().getPath().append(SRC_RES),
                                                EXCLUDE_ALL);
        newEntries[2] = JavaCore.newSourceEntry(getCreatedElement().getPath().append(SRC_TEST));
        javaProject.setRawClasspath(newEntries, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 2));
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!monitor.isCanceled())
            monitor.done();
    }
}


private int getElementsCount(File file)
{
    // return number of files and folders in the file
}
```

As you see I have 3 ticks for delete operations and 2 for setting the classpath. This is 5 plus count of the files in the source folder, if I say: 1 tick per file or folder. Now I have a problem with the method `copyFiles`. I modified the related code to work with `IProgressMonitor`:

```
private void copyFiles(File srcFolder, IContainer destFolder, IProgressMonitor monitor)
    throws CoreException, IOException
{
    for (File f : srcFolder.listFiles())
    {
        if (f.isDirectory())
        {
            IFolder newFolder = destFolder.getFolder(new Path(f.getName()));
            newFolder.create(true, true, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));
            copyFiles(f, newFolder, monitor);
        }
        else
        {
            newFile.create(new FileInputStream(f), true, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));
        }
    }
}
```

As soon one of the methods `create(...)` is called (either on `IFile` or on `IFolder`) the progress bar should be moved by 1 tick. But it doesn't move at all. What could be the reason and how to solve the problem?

**upd**: I modified the method `configureProject` as follows:

```
SubProgressMonitor copyFilesMonitor = new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, fileCount);
copyFilesMonitor.beginTask("Copying files...", fileCount);
copyFiles(templatesFolder, project, copyFilesMonitor);
copyFilesMonitor.done();
```

Now the problem is that after an invocation of `create()` (either on `IFolder` or on `IFile`) the progressbar is set to 2/3 - 2 ticks. 2/3 is designated for the whole `configureProject()` method and the last 2 ticks are to made by `setRawClasspath(...)` yet.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: You call `copyFiles` recursively so you calling `done` too early

Comment: You are right, thanks for that hint. It isn't the solution for the issue though. `done` isn't called in `copyFiles` but in `create`. It should be applied to the `SubProgressMonitor` but it is apparently applied to the parent monitor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `beginTask` (and `done`) on the `new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, fileCount)` that you are creating for the `copyFiles` method.

If you don't call `beginTask` the `worked` calls are ignored.